# eonasdan DateTimePicker autoclose doesn't work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

If I removed the autoclose it works fine. How to autoclose datetimepicker. I've been searching on this but couldn't find useful information.

```
$('#start_schedule').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        autoclose: true

    });
```

Comment: what version of the picker are you using? `autoClose: false` is designed to keep the picker open after the date gets picked and you aren't using the time component.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work actually according to documentation. If you will use `showClose: true`, it won't recognize, you will get an error. There is no other way rather than using this code in the docs. Hope this help.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
          format: 'LT'
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```