# Do the autoClose and forceParse options in the eonasdan datepicker work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I can't seem to figure out how to use the parseForce and autoClose and options for the Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker. I'm using version 4.14.30, from the docs the usage seems to be
    `$('.date-picker').datetimepicker({format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",forceParse:true});`

the console error **Uncaught TypeError: option forceParse is not recognized!** suggests that the option doesn't exist. Am I missing something?

There's a
[simillar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933819/eonasdan-datetimepicker-autoclose-doesnt-work) about the autoclose option but no real answer except a question about the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help someone out there. The correct options to use are [keepOpen](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keepopen) and [keepInvalid](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keepinvalid) and not autoClose or forceParse.

Answer (score 0):

All functions are accessed via the data attribute e.g. $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()

[enter link description here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any datepicker issues on your page, clicking anywhere automatically generates the date. In such cases, you can use the following solution

```
forceParse: false,
```

Example:

```
$(".D_DatePicker_today").datepicker({
         todayHighlight: true,
         todayBtn: true,
         format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
         autoclose: true,
         endDate: new Date(),
         forceParse: false,   
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function () {
    $('#input-birthday').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    }).data('autoclose', true);
});
```

Comment: why should he use that? Explain your answer